# Combining stream cipher with block cipher for disk encryption

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, modes-of-operation, disk-encryption

You take something like chacha20 and use the disk block # to seek it, xor it with the data block and then encrypt it with a block cipher in ECB mode.

Would this be secure?

Edit:

To avoid getting bogged down in implementation pitfalls lets consider an ideal scenario:

You have a constant size file (that is a multiple of block cipher size) that may get altered through time. Using a stream cipher to encrypt is therefore not secure under some threat models. So you combine a stream cipher with an ECB mode block cipher - through chaining, first xor with stream cipher output then pass through block cipher. Would this now be more secure? As secure as XEX/XTS?

Comment: Seeking and tweaking is not exactly the same thing. Could you describe your scheme more formally?

Comment: Agreed the title doesn't seem to fit with the body of the question. Even considering only the question and not the title, there seems to be an issue that would need work. It looks like this is a makeshift CTR mode where the block # is the counter, but with XOR instead of concatenation. If the disk block is not exactly the same size as the blocks used in a given block cipher, that would be an issue. I always think of Chacha20 as a stream cipher though.

Comment: So basically ECB mode, using a stream cipher for whitening instead of a real mode?

Comment: @forest basically yes

Comment: So an attacker would be limited to 16 bytes of malleability (as with XTS), and you have to pay the price with double the performance impact. You know, XTS internally works a lot like what you describe, but much more efficiently. It uses ECB, with a stream cipher-like function generating a random "whitening" stream for ECB encryption which requires only one block cipher call per sector. Is there a reason you can't use XTS?

Comment: Ideally I would want to just use a stream cipher as the threat models which advise against it seem to be entirely academic. If your machine is compromised worrying about bits being flipped is useless, you likely have a hardware keylogger installed. Same goes for some fantasy adversary taking routine snapshots of your filesystem. I'm just worried I'm missing something else.

Comment: @Crombie4447 It is far from academic. Malleability attacks have actually been demonstrated on perfectly average systems. No need to try to re-invent your own version of ECB mixing when good ones exist.

Comment: Only with access to hardware though, correct? Under such a compromise I would assume you are totally screwed regardless of what an adversary chooses to do.

Comment: That's generally correct, and even a malleable cipher is safe if you only care about data at rest security and not tampering (which may or may not be a wise threat model). But if that were the case, why would you go to the lengths of combining a stream cipher with ECB, since that would be done to resist malleability (and poorly, as XTS does it just as well and more efficiently)?

Comment: The snapshot aspect of it was giving me some pause, especially if it is perhaps possible to recover past states on a HDD.

Comment: The technique you gave would not help against those kinds of attacks. It would be as vulnerable as XTS.

Comment: But XTS isn't. I don't mean about change in data but rather xoring old data with new data as would happen with a stream cipher. That would be far too revealing.

Comment: I still don't get why you don't use a good standard like XTS though...

Comment: I didn't like it, smelled too much of bureaucracy. Especially the need for two distinct keys when only one is needed. But you are probably correct.

Comment: The two distinct keys was a silly mistake caused by misinterpreting recommendations when adding ciphertext stealing to XEX. It doesn't decrease security at all. In fact, under the correct conditions, XTS has been proven to be indistinguishable from random data. Malleability-wise (and snapshot-wise), it would probably be better to use a wide-block mode like EME2 or XCB, but those cut performance in half and are not widely supported by encryption software. Naturally AEAD is also fine, but it requires extra storage space for authentication tags so it's not ideal for FDE...